# Negative option prices for certain input values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, quantitative-finance

In the course of testing an algorithm I computed option prices for random input values using the standard pricing function **`blsprice`** implemented in MATLAB's Financial Toolbox.

Surprisingly <sub>( at least for me )</sub> ,
the function seems to return negative option prices for certain combinations of input values.

As an example take the following:

```
> [Call,Put]=blsprice(67.6201,170.3190,0.0129,0.80,0.1277)

Call =-7.2942e-15
Put = 100.9502
```

If I change time to expiration to `0.79` or `0.81`, the value becomes non-negative as I would expect.

Did anyone of you ever experience something similar and can come up with a short explanation why that happens?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [quant.se]? However, since the value is so tiny I would suspect it is just a [floating point error](http://floating-point-gui.de/) due to truncation at some point in the internal calculations. Maybe consider rounding off to a suitable precision, say 4 decimal points? Then the `Call` price becomes `0`.

Comment: It might also be a good question to ask MathWorks support by filing a [service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs). It might be a bug or they may just not enforce a boundary condition. You may also be able to look at the underlying code (if it's not compiled or `pcode`ed) to see what's going on: type `edit blsprice` in your Command Window.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of the Financial Toolbox you are using but for me (TB 2007b) it works fine.

When running:

`[Call,Put]=blsprice(67.6201,170.3190,0.0129,0.80,0.1277)`

I get the following:

```
Call = 9.3930e-016
Put = 100.9502
```

Which is indeed positive

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but I have come across things like this before. The small negative value can be attributed to numerical rounding error and / or truncation error within the routine used to compute the cumulative normal distribution.

As you know computers are not perfect and small numerical error always persists in all calculations, in my view therefore the question one should must ask instead is - what is the accuracy of the input parameters being used and therefore what is the error tolerance for outputs.

The way I thought about it when I encountered it before was that, in finance, typical annual stock price return variance are of the order of 30% which means the mean returns are typically sampled with standard error of roughly 30% / sqrt(N) which is roughly of the order of +/- 1% assuming 2 years worth of data (so N = 260 x 2 = 520, any more data you have the other problem of stationarity assumption). Therefore on that basis the answer you got above could have been interpreted as zero given the error tolerance.

Also we typically work to penny / cent accuracy and again on that basis the answer you had could be interpreted as zero.

Just thought I'd give my 2c hope this is helpful in some ways if you are still checking for answers!

Comment: Indeed glad you took a step, + a lovely view on weakness of models assumptions ( stationarity ) and a required scale of observations to exhibit the character of a non-random process distribution of *"residuals"*. Almost all fintech models are flawed in this sense - using **naked mathematics**, disconnected from the reality of discrete nature of the problem-domain ( unless using principally bottom-to-top discretised ( quantum-stepped ) values and computational tools, that fully respect such principal discontinuity of values and keep "stepping" internally ( even in gradients etc. ) ). A lot fun!